# POST request with href

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a post request with href requests( I need my page to redirect to the page after with a parameter in the url)
Here's the code that checks the POST request if it can help:

```
if ($_POST['pw'] == 'password') {
    echo ('<iframe height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no"  src="html/book.html?pw=passcode&ver=2014_09_29_11:08&" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen />');
} else {
    die ("<h1>Access Denied !</h1>");
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? You can't make post requests with href obviously. Tell me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: You understood, maybe I could do this with a form.. idk, searched on google but found nothing :/

Comment: Why don't you use a form/button?

Comment: really not clear what you want

Comment: lxg, with button it would be ugly for my site :/
Dagon, i'm trying to make a post request with an href, like we can do with a form and a button

Comment: @davidp027 Style the form and button so it doesn't look ugly then! That is what css is there for.

Comment: @ialarmedalien: True, but keep in mind that `<form>`s are block elements, so even with proper styling, it may be impossible.

Comment: I'm not good with css xD always using bootstrap or other that I find online & It's a list of href so I would like to make a 10 buttons under each other that's why it would look not really good

Comment: @lxg with css, almost all things are possible. `<div>`s are block elements, and I haven't noticed that stopping people from doing all kind of things with them.

Comment: @davidp027 You cannot send a POST request in a URL if you want to pass information in the request. You can use a GET request, but if you're sending passwords, that is not a good idea. I'm afraid you're going to have to do some work and find out how to style buttons to look like text links. It is not difficult, don't worry!

Comment: The use of **href** in the question is confusing and misleading. `href` is an _attribute_ on an HTML tag. `POST` (and GET) are **HTTP** verbs. You **must** have a URL that you are posting to, and I assume that's what you mean by "href" here. The URL that you POST to **is allowed** to have URL parameters, as Samitch points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain HTML, you cannot send a `href` request as POST, they are GET requests by definition.

But, you could use JavaScript to intercept the call and submit a hidden form. Here's an example. I'll use jQuery, but of course this can also be done with plain JS.

```html
<a href='somepage.php' id='mylink'>link text</a>
```

In the JS, we catch the `click` event and insert a form on the fly which we will send via POST afterwards. Of course, you don't need to generate the form with JS, you can as well insert the form as plain HTML directly into the page.

```javascript
$("#mylink").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // don't "execute" the link

  var $form = $("<form action='somepage.php' method='post' style='display: none' target='_blank'>" +
    "<input type='hidden' name='foo' value='bar' />" +
    "<input type='submit' />" + 
    "</form>").appendTo($('body'));

  $form.submit();
});
```

As you're composing the template in PHP anyway, you can insert the correct `input` elements and the `action` attribute of the form on the server side.

The sophisticated way, however, would be to parse the URL in the `href` attribute of the link. But that's a whole different topic, so I'll omit that for the sake of brevity.

**Security warning:** It is of course a good idea not to send passwords via GET requests. However, this solution expects that JS is enabled on the user's browser. If it isn't, or the code doesn't work, **the request will be sent via GET** anyway.

The proper way would be to use a real `<form>` element or AJAX to send post requests.

Comment: The javascript dosen't run when i click on the href, only redirects to the page with a normal request

Comment: The example uses jQuery; if you don't load jQuery, the code will just cause an error and not execute. Also, there is no `onload` handler, so the script must be placed after the link in the HTML, unless you're wrapping it into `onload` yourself.

Comment: Oh didn't know about jQuery, I need to learn javascript stuff...Never used it until now but it perfectly works now ! Thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot make an HTTP POST request with either a `src` or an `href` attribute, only HTTP GET requests can be made this way.

`GET` requests pass their parameters in the URL via the query string and have empty request bodies. They look like:

```
GET /page.php?var1=foo&var2=bar HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

`POST` requests pass their parameters in the request body. They look like

```
POST /page.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

var1=foo&var2=bar
```

You *may* make a `POST` request that also includes `GET` parameters, but this is technically bad practice and relies on having tolerant web servers and CGI gateways that allow this. eg:

```
POST /page.php?var1=foo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

var2=bar
```

Given the context of your question it should be mentioned that POST requests are only marginally more secure for password transmission because they do not include the password in the query string which might be logged by the server or stored in the history of the browser. **However, they are still transmitted in plain text**,which should be apparent from the above examples.

Use SSL.

Additionally, any information returned to the client will likely be cached in the browser, so sending back `<iframe src="/page.php?password=foobar ...>` is also very bad security practice. Use sessions for local authentication and passwordless authentication schemes like OAuth for remote authentication.

Comment: Very didactic explanation, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($_POST['pw'] == 'password') {
    header('location:#####FULL URL HERE#######');
 else {
    die ("Invalid password");
```

Comment: This code already work, but it's the POST request that I can't find how to do using href's

Comment: 'if ($_POST['pw'] == 'password') {
    echo ('<iframe height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no"  src="html/book.html?pw='.$_POST['pw'].'&ver=2014_09_29_11:08&" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen />');'
} else {
    die ("<h1>Access Denied !</h1>");
}

Comment: @Billy: You're missing the point. The question is about having a HTML `<a href=''>` element submit a POST request, instead of the default GET.

Comment: @davidp027 - you are confusing two different levels of web technology: "POST" is HTTP, while "href" is HTML.